# Is it necessary to start a new thread in the channelread method to execute the business logic even if business logic is a pure CPU operation?

Tags: java, netty

I see the following code(A server based on netty):

```
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        // Release IO thread
        AllChannelHandler.channelRead(() -> {
            // business logic...
            // response
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new Object());
        });
    }
    // other code

}
```

And this is `AllChannelHandler#channelRead`:

```
public class AllChannelHandler {

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            new SynchronousQueue<>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());


    public static void channelRead(Runnable r) {
        executor.execute(r);
    }

}
```

If business logic is a IO operation, It's easy to understand to start a new thread to do this operation.

But i wonder is it necessary to start a new thread in the channelread method to execute the business logic even if business logic is a pure CPU operation ?

Comment: Yes it is. You don't want to delay other clients while you compute this response.

Comment: But doesn't that consume a lot of thread resources?(Although thread pools are used.If you have a large number of client connections at the same time, you may need many threads)@user207421

Comment: Yes, you may need many threads depending on how expensive your business logic is in CPU cycles, but the point is that you want Netty's I/O threads to be doing I/O.

Comment: Not doing  I/O,memory-based operations@SeanBright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your business logic is performing blocking IO, than you have to do it in another thread to avoid blocking the event loop.

But if you have a non-blocking API (like when the IO operation is based on NIO), you don't have to block the thread and you don't need a new thread - you need continuation.

I explained how this can be done in Netty here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722136/382683

BTW, for the blocking code there's also a neater solution provided by netty as described here: https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html
(look for "**Building a pipeline**")

Comment: Thanks ! So,`pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());` and do business logic in a new thread  achieve the same effect?

Comment: @ppbb It achieves the same effect as the code you posted yes. However, for best performance, it's best to work non-blocking all the way, and use a thread per core model. This gains best performance for most workloads

Comment: It helped me a lot.But I have a question why non-blocking  api  gains best performance for most workloads? Isn't  `CompletableFuture & Future`  also implemented based on thread pools?

Comment: @ppbb CompletableFuture isn't based on thread pools. It's just an execution context. It's hard to explain in this media, but in general you gain performance by avoiding context switching, thread contentions, etc. Queues don't solve performance issues, nor do thread pools (and their internal queues). But when you use thread pools you have a false sense of freedom, while in fact if you push it too hard the threadpool has to drop (reject) executions or to block you upon submission, or to add an endless number of thread until you run out of resources